# How to edit /sys/ files properly without root?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, file-system, screen-brightness, selinux

I have android device with version 5.1.1 . The device is not rooted, but root can be accessed on `/system` or `/data` partition files from the custom `TWRP` recovery using `adb`.

The device has `SELINUX` enabled and is set to `Enforcing` (getenforce shows enforcing).

I have rooted this device by flashing SuperSU previously, but currently the device is not rooted and Im not willing to root it, TWRP still present.

My phone's minimum brightness is a way too much that it hurts during night. By editing the /sys/ file, i want to achieve the low brightness.
Specifically, I want to edit the file
`/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness`
which takes legal values from 1 - 255. But my phone will set this file's minimum value to 10 and not less than that. When I previously rooted this device and echoed 1 to this file, the brightness is comfortably low.
So, I want to achieve this without root.

Normally, this file is owned by `system:system` with permissions rw-r-r . The directory containing this file is owned by `root:root` with permissions rwxr-xr-x .

Im ok with unpacking, editing, and repacking boot.img files.
Actually, I did unpack the boot.img and edited the `init.rc` file to make the file permissions to rw-rw-rw and directory permissions to rwxrwxrwx . But still, I wasn't able to echo any value to this file. I tried both from adb shell and terminal app. The error I'm getting is "Permission Denied".

What am I doing wrong? How to properly edit this file without root?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible due to SELinux restrictions. You'd better get root since you can edit boot image.

Comment: On my oneplus one I don't have root but the Snapdragon battery guru app somehow manages to get it below what I can set when it enables its own power mode... So it must be possible!